# How to compile Typescript project into one file without system/amd overhead?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm working on a Typescript project that I want to compile into a single JS file for use in a web browser. I've followed a couple tutorials that want me to either use "tsc" or "npx webpack" commands. However, it seems like I need to use a TS module ("Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile.") and these add overhead that the web browser doesn't like ("ReferenceError: System is not defined").

Isn't there some way to simply say: take these TS files, compile them together, ideally minify it too, and output a JS file without some extra System thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. TypeScript is a compiler. So it compiles files to newer files preserving the directory structure.

Compiling into a single file is **essentially** a definition of module bundler. So, it is Webpack, Rollup, Parcel or equivalent.

However, there is a considerable scope for improving the DX for your compilation process. Consider using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) which would simplify all of this setup for you. Everything via just one command! Instead of using TypeScript CLI, you would use Vite CLI with very minimal to zero config.

Finally, also look at Parcel which is marketed as zero configuration bundler. So, it should be matter of just installing it unless, you have some very specific configuration.